# Unity3D LINQ. InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, linq

Во время исполнения приложения у меня заполняется `List <object> _myList` необходимыми мне объектами, используя `Couroutine`.

В `Update` я перебираю свой список `_myList`, используя метод расширения `.First()`.

Но во время перебора списка, у меня выбрасывается исключение: `InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object`

Перед перебором списка, делаю проверку на `null`.

Связи с чем генерируется исключение?

Answer (score 4):

Перебор коллекции может привести к `InvalidOperationException` если во время перебора изменить коллекцию.

Comment: А как избежать этого? Без `lock`.

Comment: @rdorn глупый совет - `ToList()` упадет точно с такой же ошибкой

Comment: точно, что-то тупнул, сорри.

Comment: Я сделал событие для синхронизации и использовал `.ToList()`, помогло.
Но при этом вылетает на такой LINQ запрос в `Update()`:
`element = myList.First(x => Vector3.Distance(x.gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.position) <= radius);`

Answer (score 0):

Хочу напомнить, что корутины и update выполняются в одном и том же потоке. Это я к тому, что Вы упомянули про lock.
Убедитесь, что в коллекции точно будут элементы, которые удовлетворяют предикату, а лучше замените First на FirstOrDefault и потом проверяйте на null.